# How to save all the outputs of a for loop - java

Tags: java, math, factoring

In java i am trying to make a program to do my math homework (not to actually cheat, just trying to learn java) and i have a for loop that gets me all the factors of the given number, but i can't figure out how to save all of the outputs of the for loop in pairs ( if possible) to test later in the math problem to solve it, here is the code. (will add needed info on request, first post)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class factoring {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String varible;
    String secondOperator;
    String firstOperator;
    int power;
    int greatestCommonFactor;
    long factorTo;
    long factorBy;
    String factors = null;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the greatest common factor (Default to 1)");
    greatestCommonFactor = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please input the varible");
    varible = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the power");
    power = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the first operator");
    firstOperator = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter what your factoring to");
    factorTo = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the second operator");
    secondOperator = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter what you're factoring by");
    factorBy = userInput.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i * i <= factorBy; i++) {
        if (factorBy % i == 0) {
            if (i * i != factorBy) factors = factorBy / i + " and " + i;
        } 
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Perhaps use a 2 Dimensional Array.

Comment: Could i get an an example of how that would work for what I'm trying to do? i looked up some stuff on it, but I'm not really sure how to implement it with what I've read.

Comment: What exactly should the pairs contain? If you would add an example of the expected result it would be easier to understand.

Comment: @Frank the pairs would contain the factors of the given number, like lets say factorBy == 64 then the pairs would be 64 and 1, 32 and 2, 16 and 4, and 8 and 8

Comment: Where do you want to save the output? You don't have to loop up to factorBy, rather up to square root of factorBy  in you for loop should do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to compute the greatest common factor or divisor, called the Euclidean algorithm.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0 != b) {
        r = a%b; a = b; b = r;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file to save your result.

try the following code

```
String  loc = "Desktop/Factors of "+factorBy;
File outFile = new File(loc);

if(!outFile.exists())
{
    outFile = new File(loc);
}
try{

    fout = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


for(int i = 1; i * i <= factorBy; i++) {
    if (factorBy % i == 0) {
        if (i * i != factorBy){
            factors = factorBy / i + " and " + i;


            try{
                fout.write(factors.getBytes());
                fout.write("\n".getBytes());

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("factors:"+factors);
        }
    } 
}
```